# start.js:45TypeError: Not enough arguments on Safari

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm having this error in the console of Safari ( only on Safari)

start.js:45TypeError: Not enough arguments

I can not find any start.js file

Seems all my wordpress website are having this error in Safari.

Do you guys know how where is this coming from ? CAn not find anything !

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Where is `start.js` script coming from? Doesn't sound like part of WP core on top of my head.